# What can cause robot framework to stop working?

Tags: robotframework

Having used robot framework for almost a year, it suddenly stopped working. Starting a script gives only the response

```
'pybot' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Running scripts worked yesterday, and I can't remember making any changes since then. I have checked the environment variables, they haven't been changed. The installation is on a Windows Server 2012. Python is still working as usual. There is no difference between using `pybot` or `robot`.

Now I just don't know what else to look for, and I'm asking you geniuses to give some ideas on where to search for this error.

Comment: I would close this question as unable to reproduce cause the library was moved.

Answer (score 0):

One of two things happened:

1. robot framework was uninstalled
2. something in your environment changed so that pybot is no longer on your PATH

Both of those should be very easy to verify.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the python/scripts folder had been moved by someone into the python/Lib folder. Simply putting it back solved the issue.